# Change the background label

Tags: java, android, xml, material-design, android-textinputlayout

I have tried in many ways to change the background color that is seen on my label and I have not been able to,As you can see, the background of my label is blue, I want to change it to another color.

How can I do this?

[image]

Code

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputlogInPasword"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLogInName">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/TextInputPasword"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:background="@color/your_color` or `android:backgroundTint="@color/your_color` to change the background color.

Comment: no working , i want to change the background the label (usuario).